# How iterate this JSON object with jQuery/regular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a JSON object, how do I print all values?`

Sample:

```
{"firstname":{"isEmpty":"Value is required and can't be empty"},"email":{"isEmpty":"Value is required and can't be empty"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for .. in` to loop over the members of an object:

```
var i, obj = {{your json object}};

for (i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i + ": " + obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Your object has nested objects inside it, so you may need to have two nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

A "JSON-object" is actually just a Javascript-object in text-notation. So all you have to do at clientside, is to parse that string with either well known and available methods or (slightly worse) `eval` that string.

Example:

```
var jsonString = '{"firstname":{"isEmpty":"Value is required and cannot be empty"},"email":{"isEmpty":"Value is required and cannot be empty"}}'

var myParsedObject = JSON.parse( jsonString );

for(var key in myParsedObject) {
    if( myParsedObject.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
        console.log(key, ': ', myParsedObject[key]);
}
```

`JSON.parse` will do exactly the above desribed. It converts the object text notation into a true Javascript object. Once that is done, we can simply loop over it's keys and access its propertys using `for..in`.

Doing it more "newschool'ish" we would do it with ES5, like

```
var myParsedObject = JSON.parse( jsonString );
Object.keys( myParsedObject ).forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log(key, ': ', myParsedObject[key]);
});
```

Comment: @cony Use json2.js for non-Web 2.0 compatible browsers like IE6: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

Just as if it's an associative array.

```
for (k in object){
    //You don't need printing source codes of object methods, right?
    if (typeof object[k] != 'function'){
        document.write(object[k]);
    }
}
```